# Confusions regarding oscillator in black body and value of one quantum

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, electrons

Q 1 By saying oscillator I.e atoms in the wall of black body. Do we mean electron ? Because boundary of any atom is electron right.

Q2 My textbook say that quantum is the smallest value of energy that can be emitted or absorbed. On web , it says charge of an electron i.e 1.6*10$^{-19}$C
so , is this the smallest value and there can be a value greater than this ?

“The value of one quantum is equal to the magnitude of the charge on an electron”

Comment: (1). No, they mean an atom. To oscillate, an electron must be a part of an atom. (2). That's charge, not energy. You can't compare them. If it is not clear, wait for 1 kilogram of time and read this again.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Also , they say smallest value of quantum is charge of electron . That’s the point. Yes,they are different things. I will paste the exact definition.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple loosely correlated questions. Also, make sure you provide a complete citation for the sources you are referencing to (*my textbook* is meaningless) and write a concise title describing the question as precise as possible.

Comment: The "classical" smallest value of *charge* quantum ( as there are many quantised quantities ) is charge of electron. But it is not fully true, if subnucleon structures are considered. As the charge of u quark is +2/3 e and of d quark is -1/3 e.